# Declaring a variable in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

what is the difference between declaring a variable like `@variableName` and `$variableName` in TSQL

Comment: the `@variableName` is  for declare local session variable in tsql `@@variableName` is for global variable between sessions and `$` is for some functionality of sql server like `$partition` for access the functionality of partitioning in sql server and use in sqlcmd

Comment: @MahdiRahimi technically, @@ is for a system function. TSQL does not have global variables.

Answer (score 1):

```
1> declare @a int =6;
2> select top 10 i,"$(USERNAME)" as UserName from test where i<@a;
3> go
i           UserName
----------- --------
          1 Luuk
          2 Luuk
          3 Luuk
          4 Luuk
          5 Luuk

(5 rows affected)
1>
```

`$variableName` see: [sqlcmd - Use with Scripting Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/sqlcmd-use-with-scripting-variables?view=sql-server-ver15).

`@variableName` see: [DECLARE @local_variable (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-local-variable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)